# Find the CDF for this function

Tags: probability

Let $R$ be a continous random variable where the sample space is $-1\leq r\leq 1$ with the following probability density $$f(r) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}& \mbox{for} \quad -1 \leq r \leq 0 \\
 r+\frac{1}{4} &\mbox{for} \quad 0\lt r\leq 1\\
0 &\mbox{}\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

B) $F_R(t)$ for $-2\leq t\leq 2$. (This is the CDF)
    I got $$F_N(r) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if}\quad -2 \leq t\lt -1 \\ \frac{1}{4}t+\frac{1}{4} & \mbox{if}\quad -1\leq t\leq 0\\ \frac{1}{4}+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{1}{4}t&\mbox{if}\quad 0\lt t\leq 1 \\ 1 &\mbox{if}\quad 1\lt t\leq 2 \end{cases}   $$

C) Find the Var($\dfrac{R^3}{6})$
         The setup would be $\dfrac{1}{36}[\int_{-1}^0 \dfrac{r^6}{4} dr+\int_0^1 (r^7+\dfrac{r^6}{4}) dr-[\int_{-1}^0\dfrac{r^3}{4}+\int_0^{1}(r^4+\dfrac{r^3}{4}) dr]^2]$? Just need to see if what I have is correct thanks.

Comment: For $t\gt 1$ we have $F_R(t)=1$. Also, your cdf is not right for $0\lt t\le 1$. We want $\frac{1}{4}+\int_0^t (r+1/4)\,dr$.  The variance calculation is not correct.

Comment: I fixed the variance part. I forgot its r^3 so I increased each exponent by 3.

Comment: I don't get why the cdf for $0\lt t\leq 1$ has a $\frac{1}{4}$ added to it?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Do I have the variance correct now as well? I also fixed the problems with the CDF. I failed to realize that the CDF is a function that measures the area to the left of $r$. Thanks

Comment: That is the fundamental definition of the cdf. The $1/4$, as you figured out, is the "weight" between $-1$ and $0$. For the variance, I will write an answer. since I am typo-prone, and typos are a disaster in comments, editing has to be done quickly, and some TeX typos make an awful unfixable mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the useful fact that in general
$$\text{Var}(W)=E(W^2)-(E(W))^2.\tag{1}$$
Let $W=\frac{R^3}{6}$. So we want to find $E\left(\frac{R^6}{36}\right)$ and $E\left(\frac{R^3}{6}\right)$.

For the expectation of $\frac{R^6}{36}$, we need to calculate
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{r^6}{36}f_R(r)\,dr.$$
For the actual integration, we need only worry about the interval from $-1$ to $1$.

Since $f_R$ is defined by different formulas from $-1$ to $0$ than from $0$ to $1$, integrate separately over thse two intervals and add up.

In a similar way you can find the expectation of $\frac{R^3}{6}$. Then use (1).

**Remarks:** $1.$ The cdf is now essentially correct. But it is highly unusual to work from $-2$ to $2$. In the near universal view, the cdf is defined for *all* real numbers.

$2.$ If you prefer to avoid fractions (I do), you could compute the variance of $R^3$, and use the fact that $\text{Var}(kW)=k^2\text{Var}(W)$.

Comment: I fixed the variance now.

Comment: Hard to read, but not yet. Note that in the integral we  use the **density** function $f_R$, not the cdf $F_R$. Nowhere in your calculation should you be integrating any higher power than $r^5$. Follow the steps outlined in the answer above. Slips are easy to make, since although there is nothing hard, it is kind of messy.

Comment: Its actually R^3/6 not R^2/6. Sorry the type was really small for the exponent.

Comment: I have had trouble misreading superscript $3$ before. Am using a small and low quality (but cheap) laptop.

Comment: But recall that the variance of $W$ is $E(W^2)-(E(W))^2$. I don't see $E(W)$ being squared.

Comment: I fixed that as well.

Comment: Looks fine now. You have it, apart from the final calculation.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Today ive been making way too many mistakes that I normally would not.

Comment: You are welcome. These things can be fiddly, and can require an unpleasant amount of attention to minor details.